# Как с помощью регулярных выражений найти результат в теге

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как с помощью регулярного выражения найти только значение тега, а не тег полностью. К примеру есть тег:

```
<span class="someClass">30 000 у.е.</span>
```

Я нахожу регулярным выражением

```
/<span class="someClass">.+?</span>/
```

но при этом забирается весь тег, а мне надо только то что внутри, как мне это сделать? Написать ещё одно регулярное выражение? которое будет ещё раз выбирать из этого цифры? Или можно сделать однми регулярным выражением, учитывая что вся страница будет доступна в виде строки с кучей ненужного

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто необходимо объединить часть совпадения в группу:

```
/<span class="someClass">(.+?)</span>/
```

Функции осуществляющие поиск при помощи этого регулярного выражения сохранят в массив с нулевым элементом- все совпадение целиком, в первый элемент- часть совпадения, которая будет соответствовать первой группе регулярного выражения, то есть тексту между `<span class="someClass">` и `</span>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="someClass">(.+)</span>
```

Или лучше так:

```
<span class="someClass">([\s0-9y.e]+)</span>
```

Comment: ну правильно, но при этом я получаю весь тег нельзя ли одним рег выражением найти по span но в выражение его не включать?

Comment: @Stee1House, в этом случае весь тег будет первым совпадением, а подмаска - вторым.

Comment: @node_pro, мне кажется, стоит вернуть на место вопросительный знак, он означает минимальную квантификацию и очень важен для этого регулярного выражения. А вариант «лучше» совсем сотрите, ибо там фигня какая-то внутри символьного класса.

Comment: @Stee1House, где это регулярное выражение вы выполняете?В какой среде? Если PHP. То Вам вернет массив match и вторым элементом ( т.е match[1]) будет то, что Вам нужно

Answer (score 0):

А нужно ли в этом случае использовать regexp?

С помощью queryselector или jquery берём искомую ноду и вытаскиваем её контент с помощью innerText или чего-то подобного.

Comment: Ну уже сделал с помощью регулярных выражений) Думаю в следующий раз испробую другой способ

Comment: как знаешь. но. никогда. никогда. никогда не работай регулярками там, где можно решить задачу без них. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @norbornen анализировать регулярными выражениями можно и нужно если есть небольшие данные, которые просто и быстро просчитываются регулярками. Либо дом регулярками проверять либо отдельный тег...большая разница.

Comment: @MaximPro а есть предпосылки к тому, что "данные" не большие? если топикстартеру нужно работать со всем исходником то мой подход правильнее так как браузеру не нужно ничего "просчитывать" - весь дом уже загружен.

Comment: @norbornen просто не нужно отпугивать людей от рег выражений. Ну а в целом да можно взять инструменты, которые дом сами уже обработали, осталось лишь указать конкретно что нужно.

Comment: @MaximPro задачу надо решать максимально эффективно. эмоциональные аргументы про "отпугивание" тут не к месту

Comment: @norbornen да нет тут никаких эмоций, просто некоторые негативно к ним относятся в целом. Я понимаю что для решения этой задачи ваш ответ хорош, но я думаю что стоит пояснять чем плохи рег и в каких ситуациях, а не просто говорить что они плохи. На этом все.